# Annotation exception: Unknown mappedBy error in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, exception, annotations, jta

I am using hibernate version 5 and getting below error when I try to do bi-directional one-to-one mapping with my employee and address entities.

> Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown
>   mappedBy in: home.practice.Employee.addr, referenced property unknown:
>   home.practice.Address.employee    at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.OneToOneSecondPass.doSecondPass(OneToOneSecondPass.java:147)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1659)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1634)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:278)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:692)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
>     at home.practice.mainClass.main(mainClass.java:24)

Entity Employee

```
package home.practice;


import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;




    @Entity
    @Table(name="EMP")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="seq", sequenceName="TAB_CUSTOMER_SEQ", allocationSize=100)
    public class Employee implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="seq")
    @Column(name="EMPNO",unique=true,nullable=false,length=6)
    private int empno;

    @Column(name="ENAME",unique=false,nullable=false,length=20)
    private String name;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="employee",cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    private Address addr;

    public Address getAddr() {
        return addr;
    }
    public void setAddr(Address addr) {
        this.addr = addr;
    }
    public int getEmpno() {
        return empno;
    }
    public void setEmpno(int empno) {
        this.empno = empno;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    }
```

**Address Entity**

```
package home.practice;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.PrimaryKeyJoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter;
@Entity
@Table(name="ADDRESS")
public class Address implements Serializable{

@Column(name="address_line1")
private String line1;
@Column(name="address_line2")
private String line2;
@Column(name="zip")
private long zip;   

@OneToOne
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
private Employee employee;

@Id
@Column(name="EMPNO",unique=true,nullable=false,length=6)
@GeneratedValue( generator="gen")
@GenericGenerator(name="gen", strategy = "foreign",parameters={ @Parameter(name="property",value="employee")})
private int empno;



public Employee getEmployee() {
    return employee;
}
public void setEmployee(Employee employee) {
    this.employee = employee;
}
public int getEmpno() {
    return empno;
}
public void setEmpno(int empno) {
    this.empno = empno;
}
public int getAddressId() {
    return AddressId;
}
public void setAddressId(int addressId) {
    AddressId = addressId;
}
@Id
int AddressId;

public String getLine1() {
    return line1;
}
public void setLine1(String line1) {
    this.line1 = line1;
}
public String getLine2() {
    return line2;
}
public void setLine2(String line2) {
    this.line2 = line2;
}
public long getZip() {
    return zip;
}
public void setZip(long zip) {
    this.zip = zip;
}
}
```

Can someone have a look at this and let me know if it is bug in hibernate or I am missing something in my code? I have already tried some of the solutions to same problem in other threads but to no avail. There was a similar bug in hibernate earlier but was fixed in 4.2 version.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved this problem:

I missed in my hibernate configuration file:
`<mapping class="home.practice.Address"/>`

I earlier defined
  `<mapping class="home.practice.Employee"/>` but not the address class.